# The integer part of $x+1$ is the integer part of $x$ plus $1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do you solve the proof:

If $x$ is a real number, then: $[x+1]  = [x] + 1$.

For my proof, I tried to describe the interior of the argument inside the parentheses, but I was unsuccessful. Please help!

Comment: What are the brackets referring to? What does your notation mean?

Comment: Probably $[\cdot]$ denotes the floor function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = [x] \Rightarrow x-1 <y \leq x\Rightarrow x < y+1 \leq x+1\rightarrow y+1 = [x+1]\Rightarrow [x]+1=[x+1]$